# Updating a nested value in an NSDictionary

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary, nsobject

I've initialized a dictionary of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]` so I can save it into `NSUserDefaults`.

Here's what it looks like:

```
var allMetadata: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [
    String: [String: String]
    // Example: "project30": ["deliverablepath": "hello"]
]
```

I give `deliverablepath` a value from the very beginning, and later on I want to update it. I've tried this:

```
allMetadata[arrayOfProjectIDs[index]]!["deliverablepath"]! = "goodbye"
```

But I get the error

> Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is '(NSObject,
>   AnyObject)'

I know about `updateValue()`, but it seems to overwrite adjacent keys in the first nested layer, so it's not working for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's in your `arrayOFProjectIDs`?

Comment: @Aaron It's an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use question optional to avoid "let pyramid"

```
var allMetadata: [String: [String: String]] = ["a": ["b": "c"]]
allMetadata["a"]?["b"] = "z" // ok!
allMetadata["q"]?["b"] = "d" // nil
```

UPD:
If you want to cast directly, you should try this:

```
var allMetadata: [NSObject: AnyObject] = ["a": ["b": "c"]]
if var dict = allMetadata["a"] as? [String: String] {
    dict["b"] = "z"

    // for dict update, because it's value typed
    allMetadata["a"] = dict
}
```

Mention, that I've written "var", not "let" in condition.

Comment: This gives the error "Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is '(NSObject, AnyObject)'" and prompts me to delete the question mark. I know it has to do with typing the dictionary as <NSObject: AnyObject>, but if I change that, it won't let me save to / load from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @Naftali Beder I am sure you can save the dictionary to NSUserDefaults using NSUserDefaults().setObject(allMetadata, forKey: "allMetadata"). You can then load it back using NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("allMetadata") as [String:[String:String]]

Comment: @dimpiax Your update would overwrite any other values saved under the key "a" - my issue is that if "a" also has a value ["d": "e"], I don't want to overwrite that.

Comment: it won't. try to set initial data: ["a": ["b": "c", "k": "i"]].
Did you check?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a safe way, it is best to do this in an *if let pyramid* as follows:

```
if let projectId = arrayOfProjectIDs[index] {
    if var project = allMetadata[projectId] as? [String:String] {
        project["deliverablePath"] = "Goodbye"
    }
}
```

That is not too bad actually.

Comment: Unfortunately on the line where the renaming takes place, I get the error "'@lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'AnyObject!'" It seems to me that your code is trying to rename a constant derived from the dictionary value (not the dictionary value itself), which I don't think is possible. Maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: because code hasn't casting to [String: String] of project value.

Comment: Thanks! Added a cast to `[String:String]`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to give an alternative answer here.

I understand the original question is about how to deal with nested arrays and dictionaries, but I think it is worth mentioning that this kind of data model may be better implemented with a more formal API.

For example, how about this:

```
class Project {
    var id: String
    var deliverablePath: String
    ... etc ...
}

class ProjectRepository {
    func getProjectWithId(id: String) -> Project? {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can use high level code like:

```
if let project = repository.getProjectWithId("") {
    project.deliverablePath = "Goodbye"
}
```

Underneath you can still implement this with dictionaries and arrays of course.

Comment: This is the kind of answer that gets me learning something new, so thank you for this.